# Continuity on an open interval implies uniform continuity on that interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

I have that $f$ is continuous on $[0, \infty)$. I want to show that $f$ is also uniformly continuous on this interval.

We know that $f$ is continuous on all intervals of the form $[0,n]$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So then $f$ is uniformly continuous on all $[0,n]$.

Now consider $x,y\in [0, \infty)$. Either $x\in [0,n]$ and $y\in [0,n']$, $n\neq n'$. WLOG suppose that $n'>n$. So then $x\in [0, n']$ as well. Since $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, n']$, we can find an appropriate $\delta$.

If $x,y\in [0,n]$, then, of course, we can also find the appropriate $\delta$ (since $f$ is uniformly continuous on this interval).

Thank you.

Comment: This is false. $f(x)=x^{2}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: $\delta$ will generally depend on $n$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I am having trouble understanding which part of the proof is mistaken. Thanks.

Comment: Your $\delta$ each depend on $n$, it's not a single $\delta$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I have updated it. Thanks.

Comment: Uniform continuity is a global property, not a local one; we can't check uniform continuity by fixing two arbitrary points in the domain. (The issue of $n$-dependence of $\delta$ persists after the edit. If we assume $f$ has a limit at $\infty$, however, we can get the necessary global control.)

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223626/proving-uniform-continuity-from-the-supposition-of-continuity-on-an-interval ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving uniform continuity from the supposition of continuity (on an interval)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4223626/proving-uniform-continuity-from-the-supposition-of-continuity-on-an-interval)